# Vue JS - Use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "page"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I use pagination, method `nextPage` works without error, but when I want to go back I get an error

Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "page"

This error is related to the `previousPage` method. As I understand it, I'm trying to directly change the `page`, but how can I solve this problem?

```
<div>
  <span
    @click="previousPage"
  >
  </span>
  <span
    @click="nextPage"
  >
  </span>
</div>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
    "results",
    "is_loading",
    "search",
    "page",
    "previous",
    "next",
    "pages_results"
  ],

  methods: {
    nextPage: function() {
      if (this.pages_results[this.page + 1]) {
        this.pages_results[this.page + 1].array;
        this.pages_results[this.page + 1].next;
        this.pages_results[this.page + 1].previous;
        this.page++;
      } else {
        this.next && this.search(this.page + 1);
      }
    },
    previousPage: function() {
      if (this.pages_results[this.page - 1]) {
        this.pages_results[this.page - 1].array;
        this.pages_results[this.page - 1].next;
        this.pages_results[this.page - 1].previous;
        this.page--;
      } else {
        this.previous && this.search(this.page - 1);
      }
    },
    load() {
      this.search(this.page + 3);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Although it is not part of your question, you have many lines of code that do nothing: `this.pages_results[this.page + 1].array;
        this.pages_results[this.page + 1].next;
        this.pages_results[this.page + 1].previous;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is store the property on a data field.

In this case your data object would look like this:

```
data() {
    return {
       pageNumber: this.page
    };
}
```

Then in the method where you use it, set `this.pageNumber++`